# Creating a custom nfsmapid id_resolver

Tags: nfs

According to the documentation of nfsmapid

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nfsidmap.5.html

It is possible to create your custom resolver by adding a line like this

```
create    id_resolver    uid:*     *    /some/other/program %k %d
```

In the file `/etc/request-key.conf`

So I created a test script that simply creates a file that prints %k %d to a local text file just o see how this would work. As I understand it each time a request for some UID or GID is generated (by doing ls -la, for example) it should invoke my script. Is this not the case?

Should I restart some service in order to get this to work? Also how would I return the value (string) of the UID or GID that is being queried?

Comment: Such a great unanswered question.